# Comparing Gridview Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two gridviews, and I need to compare the results by column. Sometimes one of the gridviews might have columns which are not in the other one, thus I need to compare only those columns which exist in both grids.

The code i have written actually goes through every cell of each row, it starts at row 0 cell 0 and continue row 0 cell 1 and then goes to the next row. However, I would like to cell have it in a way that if the column in say Grid 2 exists in Grid 1 i would go through it's cells and then pass to the next column. Below is the code i have:

```
List<String> columnsGrid43 = new List<String>();

foreach (TableCell cell in gridReport43.Rows[0].Cells)
{
    BoundField fieldGrid43 = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)cell).ContainingField;
    columnsGrid43.Add(fieldGrid43.DataField);
}

foreach (TableCell cell in gridReport44.Rows[0].Cells)
{
    BoundField fieldReportGrid44 = (BoundField)((DataControlFieldCell)cell).ContainingField;
    if (columnsGrid43.Contains(fieldReportGrid44.DataField))
    {
        for (int countRow = 0; countRow < gridReport44.Rows.Count; countRow++)
        {
            for (int countCell = 0; countCell < gridReport44.Rows[countRow].Cells.Count; countCell++)
            {
                string grid1Value = gridReport43.Rows[countRow].Cells[countCell].Text;
                string grid2Value = gridReport44.Rows[countRow].Cells[countCell].Text;
                if (grid2Value.Contains(grid1Value))
                {
                    gridReport43.Rows[countRow].Cells[countCell].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(101, 226, 75);
                    gridReport44.Rows[countRow].Cells[countCell].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(101, 226, 75);
                }
                else
                {
                    gridReport43.Rows[countRow].Cells[countCell].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 102, 102);
                    gridReport44.Rows[countRow].Cells[countCell].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 102, 102);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to compare two DataTables of you two GridViews, il very easy.

Yous can use differents method on `DataTable.Rows` such as : `Contains, Find or CopyTo`

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.datarowcollection.aspx

Here sample of code :

```
    public static void CompareRows(DataTable table1, DataTable table2)
    {
    foreach (DataRow row1 in table1.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataRow row2 in table2.Rows)
        {
        var array1 = row1.ItemArray;
        var array2 = row2.ItemArray;

        if (array1.SequenceEqual(array2))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Equal: {0} {1}", row1["ColumnName"], row2["ColumnName"]);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not equal: {0} {1}", row1["ColumnName"], row2["ColumnName"]);
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: ok currently on button click i bind grid 1 to datatable and bind grid 2 to datatable, so before binding i should go the comparison and then bind the modified datatable to one of the grids

Comment: Exactly chris operate compare before bind, you can also store youer table in ViewState or Session , and compare after printing